# iOS increase touch area for UIButton in TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` in my `UITableViewCell`

I made a subclass of `UIButton` override the `pointInside` function:

```
var touchMargin:CGFloat = 20.0

override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let extendedArea = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -touchMargin, -touchMargin)
    return CGRectContainsPoint(extendedArea, point)
}
```

However, the touch area does not get increased.
I get a touch on the table cell if I touch slightly outside of the `UIButton`.

Does this code not work due to the Button being placed in a cell?

How can I fix?

Comment: increase width/height of button if there is not problem.what are the other subview's of cell?

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3**

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  test
//
//  Created by David Seek on 9/29/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 David Seek. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = MyButton(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.addedTouchArea = 50 // any value you want
        button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.action), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func action() {
        print("touched")
    }

}

class MyButton: UIButton {
    var addedTouchArea = CGFloat(0)

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

        let newBound = CGRect(
            x: self.bounds.origin.x - addedTouchArea,
            y: self.bounds.origin.y - addedTouchArea,
            width: self.bounds.width + 2 * addedTouchArea,
            height: self.bounds.width + 2 * addedTouchArea
        )
        return newBound.contains(point)
    }
}
```

You are creating a `UIButton` in the size of 100x100, and with `.addedTouchArea`, you have a UIButton - still optical size 100x100, but with a touch area of 150x150.

**Swift 2.X**

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    var addedTouchArea = CGFloat(0)

    override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {

        let newBound = CGRect(
            x: self.bounds.origin.x - addedTouchArea,
            y: self.bounds.origin.y - addedTouchArea,
            width: self.bounds.width + 2 * addedTouchArea,
            height: self.bounds.width + 2 * addedTouchArea
        )
        return newBound.contains(point)
    }
}
```

**InterfaceBuilder**

If you did set the Button with the `InterfaceBuilder`, apply our subclass of `UIButton` to your button.

[image]

Then set an outlet to the button, f.e. named buttonXY. And set `buttonXY.addedTouchArea = 50` within `viewDidLoad`, f.e.

**UITableViewCell**

Since you're asking for `UITableViewCell`. It works exactly the same.

In your ViewController class:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

        cell.myButton.addedTouchArea = 50 // any value you want
        tableView.rowHeight = 200

        return cell
    }
}
```

In your Cell class:

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: MyButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func myButtonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        print("touched")
    }
}
```

The only thing you should beware of: The outlet got set as a `UIButton` outlet, even tho I had declared it as subclass of MyButton within the `InterfaceBuilder`. I had to change the outlet manually to `MyButton`! `@IBOutlet weak var myButton: MyButton!`

Comment: Will the tableview not take the selection when you tap on the cell, when you have set didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: No. I have used it in a big project of mine as well as in a project JUST LIKE THIS to test it here for you. If you hit the button, didSelectRowAtIndexPath will not get triggered. if you hit the cell other than the hit-area of the button, didSelectRowAtIndexPath will - of course - get triggered

Comment: @user694688 any news on your side?

Comment: What if the button is inside a stack view.

Comment: what happened to the bounty?

Comment: See the [post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33101714/revisions), *no winning answers*.

Comment: why the heck? my answer does perfectly answer the question... this is just unfair...

Answer (score 6):

you should override hitTest on the view that you want to enlarge.

e.g.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (!self.isUserInteractionEnabled || self.isHidden || self.alpha <= 0.01) {
        return nil;
    }
    CGRect touchRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, -10, -10);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(touchRect, point)) {
        //TODO!? check supviews
        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create UIButton subclass:

```
class ButtonWithTouchSize: UIButton {

    var touchAreaPadding: UIEdgeInsets? = nil

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        if let inset = touchAreaPadding {
            let origin = CGPoint(x: 0 - inset.left, y: 0 - inset.top)
            let size = CGSize(width: inset.left + bounds.width + inset.right,
                              height: inset.top + bounds.height + inset.bottom)
            let rect = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
            return rect.contains(point)
        } else { 
            return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
        }
    }
}
```

If you put an instance of ButtonWithTouchSize directly into UITableViewCell contentView, you'll get it. But if you wrap this instance in some container wich is in UITableViewCell contentView, your should also override its point(inside:with) method:

```
class ContainerView: UIView {

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return btn.point(inside: point, with: event)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        btn.frame = self.bounds
    }

    private let btn: ButtonWithTouchSize = ButtonWithTouchSize()

}
```

So, to sum up... you should override point(inside:with) for each superview, which size is lessThanOrEqual to button size